# Android ArrayAdapter Filter not working properly

Tags: android, listview, search, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem using a filter with ArrayAdapter.

I have a ListView that gets published with data. Above the ListView there is an EditText Field which has a TextChangeListener on it. When entering a char sequence which definitely occurs in the ListView, under some circumstances the ListView stays empty afterwards. The elements in the ListView are formatted like this:

```
FFI 01 Jacket
Test, User
Locker 101
----------------
FFI 01 Helmet
Test, User
Locker 101
----------------
FFI 02 Jacket
Test, User2
Locker 102
----------------
.
.
.
```

and so on.

- If I search for "FFI", "01", "02", "Jacket" or "Helmet", only items with the filtered text in it are left.
- If I search for "User", "User2", "101" or "102", only items with the filtered text in it are left.
- If I seach for "Test" or "Locker", the ListView is empty.

Here is my Code:

TextChangeListener:

```
eText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    if (!cs.equals(null) || !cs.equals("") || !cs.equals(" ")) {
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
});
```

Populating Adapter and ListView:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + "AUSRUEST.DBF");
DbfIterator dbfIterator = DbfEngine.getReader(file, null);
DbfHeader dbfHeader = DbfEngine.getHeader(file, null);
int numCols = dbfHeader.getCountColumns();
int numRows = dbfHeader.getCountRecords();
arrayListView = new String[numRows][numCols];
int i=0;
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
while (dbfIterator.hasMoreRecords()) {
    DbfRecord dbfRecord = dbfIterator.nextRecord();

    if (dbfRecord.getString("FW_NR") != null && !dbfRecord.getString("FW_NR").startsWith("?")) {
        String setText = dbfRecord.getString("FW_NR")+"\n"+dbfRecord.getString("STANDORT1")+"\n"+dbfRecord.getString("ABLAGE")+"\n";
        setText = setText.replace("null", "---");
        set.add(setText);
    }

    arrayListView[i][0] = dbfRecord.getString("GRUPPE2");
    arrayListView[i][1] = dbfRecord.getString("FW_NR");
    arrayListView[i][2] = dbfRecord.getString("STANDORT1");
    arrayListView[i][3] = dbfRecord.getString("ABLAGE");
    //Date date = dbfRecord.getDate("date_val");
    String test = arrayListView[i][0];
    String test1 = arrayListView[i][1];
    String test2 = arrayListView[i][2];
    String test3 = arrayListView[i][3];
    System.out.println(arrayListView[i][0] + " " + arrayListView[i][1] + " " + arrayListView[i][2] + " "+ arrayListView[i][3]);
    i++;
}
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(set);
Collections.sort(al);
System.out.println(" ");
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Replace **"\n"** `dbfRecord.getString("FW_NR")+"\n"+dbfRecord.getString("STANDORT1")+"\n"+dbfRecord.getString("ABLAGE")+"\n"`  with **"\n "** and try.

Comment: awesome thanks :) That worked. I guess it's because the filter sees "\nTest" instead of "Test" right?

Comment: Yes, its because of that only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this snippet of code:

`"\n" dbfRecord.getString("FW_NR")+"\n"+dbfRecord.getString("STAND‌​ORT1")+"\n"+dbfRecor‌​d.getString("ABLAGE"‌​)+"\n"`

with

`"\n "` and try.

Answer by Nigam Patro

Answer (score 0):

another approach to this might be ...

`public class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {}`

and then implement the methods of interface `Filterable` in class `SomeAdapter`.

the above code in general lacks the separation of duties.